# Cant apply wave in modelsim

Tags: vhdl, simulation, modelsim, intel-fpga

I am using ModelSim to simulate a 4 bit subtractor and I am trying to apply a wave constant to my inputs. When I ran the program on my school computer, I was able to right click on one of the inputs, navigate to modify and then apply wave where I chose constant and would be able to input a number in binary.

I downloaded the program on my computer and when I try to simulate and apply a wave form, the only option is force. I'm not sure what to do and couldn't find a solution to my problem online. Is there something in the settings?

Thank you.

Comment: By far the best way to apply inputs to a design under test is to write a testbench not to get your simulator to apply inputs using some proprietary technique, as the fact that you are experiencing difficulties shows.

Comment: You should write a testbench that applies constant inputs to the signals you want to observe. Check that the version of your downloaded modelsim is the same as the one you use at school, the free to use version does not offer the same possibilities

Comment: Thank you for the input, I went online and learned how to create a test bench and I got it working. I got the student license version of the modelsim software onto my computer but I guess it's not the same version as the ones on my school computers.